# Slider in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

- Hi there
  I used jetpack compose to create a program that randomly generates a range of numbers.
  And returns them to a text-view.  I
  also used a slider to set this range, but when I change the slider,
  the numbers change constantly, as if stuck in a loop. What is the
  reason for this problem? And what should I do?
  thanks

Here is my RandomGenerator Class ->

```
class RandomGenerator (
    
            private val stringSource: String,
            private val outputLength: Long = 4,
            private val startFrom: Int,
            private val to: Int) {
    
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        fun generate(): String  {
    
            return Random()
                    .ints(outputLength, startFrom, to)
                    .asSequence()
                    .map(stringSource::get)
                    .joinToString("")
        }
    }
```

Here is my Slider that returns Int

```
@Composable
fun slider() : Int
{
    var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }

    Slider(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp).size(180.dp),

            value = sliderPosition,
            valueRange = 1f..10f,
            onValueChange = {sliderPosition = it}
    )

    return sliderPosition.roundToInt()
}
```

And ...

```
 setContent {

        var msg by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(10.dp)) {

            val len = slider()

            val result = RandomGenerator(numbers, 10, 0, len).generate()

            msg = resutl

            Text(text = msg)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Changing state with a return will not work, you want to pass a lambda to 'notify' the change.

Comment: How? can you explain that, please?

Comment: have a look at the official samples and guides to compose, it seems you are missing some fundamentals of how the concept of Compose works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh the problem is that you are assigning a value to the 'msg' which is a state-holder, because of which a recomposition is triggered. It is an infinite loop.

Comment: I deleted that assigning value and the problem was solved, 
but if I also want to keep the text-view state what should I do?

Comment: Whatever (important) state is needed to be maintained, it is stored in a viewmodel. If there are multiple textviews, create an immutable list and store it inside the viewmodel or wherever might be better for your use case

Comment: Hey there's a great set of codelabs for compose. I highly recommend taking them. Just search for "Jetpack Compose Pathways" on the web, and you will find it on the official site. They will strengthen your understanding of compose